# Import cell id to a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to calculate the standard deviation up to a particular cell in Excel. The value of the first cell is known to me. I also have found the cell id of the second cell, up to which I require the standard deviation, using the ADDRESS function and saved it in another cell.

How can I import that cell id into the formula for standard deviation?

This the formula I have already tried:

```
=STDEVP(C2:(INDEX(C88,1,1)))
```

where `INDEX(C88,1,1)` is used to get last cell id that I stored in cell C88.

Comment: @Ark this edit should not be approved, it doesn't fix the capitalization problems in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=STDEV(INDIRECT("C2:"&C8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the reason that you have to look for the "2nd" cell is that you have a table that can increase in size? If so, I suggest changing your range into a table. Excel makes this quite easy with "Format as Table" on the "Home" ribbon.

If you do this, your formula will look as pretty as this:

```
=STDEV.P(Table1[Column1])
```

In addition, it resizes by itself. There is no need for hocus pocus.

A table can have a "Totals" row and it allow you to pick the function to use (yes, that includes `STDEV`).